# Function overloading and inheritance (why doesn't this work?)

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I would like to inherit from a base class and use function overloading at the same time. The function **get** is overloaded here. However, this toy example does not compile and gives me the error message:

> Error 1   error C2660: 'B::get' : function does not take 0 arguments

The base class A with overloaded function **get**:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void set(double a) { value_ = a; }
    virtual double get() { return value_; }
    virtual double get(double b) { return value_ + b; }

protected:
    double value_;
};
```

The derived class, where one version of **get** is overridden:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual double get(double b) override { return value_ + 2 * b; }
};
```

Code for testing:

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    B b;
    b.set(1.0);
    std::cout << b.get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What does work though, is if I explicitly provide both versions in the derived class:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual double get() override { return A::get(); }
    virtual double get(double b) override { return value_ + 2 * b; }
};
```

or none (however, that kind of defeats the purpose of the class ;) ):

```
class B : public A
{
public:
};
```

What am I missing here? Why do I have to provide both versions of the overloaded function (or none)?

Comment: Because its the rules of C++? `B::get` hides all instances of `A::get`, this is purely on the name. First the compiler looks up the name, that finds `B::get`, then it tries to match the arguments, that fails. There's no rule that says if the argument match fails, go back and look for some more names.

Comment: Just add `using A::get;` in `B` and then you don't have to `override` the `get` overload that doesn't take any arguments.